# File upload to server progress with django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, multipartform-data

I have a form which users can upload files to a server with (django development server, until I push code to Apache, 100 mb limit). I want to show the user a progress bar for the upload. I've read this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/679/ for instructions. But I do not know what my $progress_url would be.

Do I need to create a temporary file on the server with file upload info? Does this involve writing my own fileuploadhander? Ajax long-polling, comet? I've read a lot of things but I don't know how to implement them. The django snippet I provided is what I've tried so far, but like I said, I don't know what file to read to get the upload data. Any suggestions? Thanks!

### **EDIT**

What I'm trying to ask is how do I access the temporary data that is stored by django when a file is uploaded? I came across this function UploadedFile.temporary_file_path, but I don't know how to use it. Do I call this in my view? Is UploadedFile already defined or do I have to assign a value to it first? I've tried it like this in my view UploadedFile.temporary_file_path but it throws and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/ to show a progress bar

You will need 2 views one to get the information and the other to save file